# Finding urls containing a specific string

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I haven't used RegEx before, and everyone seems to agree that it's bad for webscraping and html in particular, but I'm not really sure how to solve my little challenge without.

I have a small Python scraper that opens 24 different webpages. In each webpage, there's links to other webpages. I want to make a simple solution that gets the links that I need and even though the webpages are somewhat similar, the links that I want are not.

The only common thing between the urls seems to be a specific string: 'uge' or 'Uge' (uge means week in Danish - and the week number changes every week, duh). It's not like the urls have a common ID or something like that I could use to target the correct ones each time.

I figure it would be possible using RegEx to go through the webpage and find all urls that has 'uge' or 'Uge' in them and then open them. But is there a way to do that using BS? And if I do it using RegEx, how would a possible solution look like?

For example, here are two of the urls I want to grab in different webpages:

http://www.domstol.dk/KobenhavnsByret/retslister/Pages/Uge45-Tvangsauktioner.aspx

http://www.domstol.dk/esbjerg/retslister/Pages/Straffesageruge32.aspx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: Thanks, Ticho. I've done resarch on RegEx but never actually used it. I'm asking the question, because I couldn't find a way to solve the problem using BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with BeautifulSoup.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
# To find just 'Uge##' or 'uge##', as specified in the question:
urls = [el["href"] for el in soup.findAll("a", href=re.compile("[Uu]ge\d+"))]
# To find without regard to case at all:
urls = [el["href"] for el in soup.findAll("a", href=re.compile("(?i)uge\d+"))]
```

Comment: Wow, that works wonderfully. I get a list of the urls, that I want. Thanks a bunch! Any idea, why alle the urls have a u' in front of them - example: u'http://www.domstol.dk/KobenhavnsByret/retslister/Pages/Uge45-Tvangsauktioner.aspx'

Comment: I 'fixed' it with some simple string formatting, but I'm still not sure why the 'u' is added.

Comment: @kabp the `u` in front of the string means that it is a unicode string ;)

Answer (score 2):

This should work... The RegEx `uge\d\d?` tells it to find "uge" followed by a digit, and possibly another one.

```
import re
for item in listofurls:
  l = re.findall("uge\d\d?", item, re.IGNORECASE):
  if l:
    print item #just do whatever you want to do when it finds it
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Coffee. It looks right but I've been fiddling around to no luck. Will give it another shot later.

Answer (score 1):

Or just use a simple for loop:

```
list_of_urls = ["""LIST GOES HERE"""]
for url in list_of_urls:
    if 'uge' in url.lower():
        # Code to execute
```

The regex expression would look something like: `uge\d\d`

Comment: Note that the foor loop does not look for a number behind "uge".

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Willy. Much appreciated even though I went with another method.